# Django CachedStaticFilesStorage in ModelAdmin Media

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm using the CachedStaticFilesStorage backend in Django 1.7 and having a problem with static files in the admin interface.

In the `ModelAdmin` class, you can define a `Media` class with static files to add to the add/change views. To apply the hash to these files, I'm using the `static` function in `django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles`. E.g.:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static

class MyAdminClass(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class Media:
        js = [
            static('app/static_file.js'),
            static('app/static_file_2.js'),
        ]
```

This appeared to be working, because the static files had already been collected before this change had been made. But, when I remove the static files and attempt to run `collectstatic` it fails with the error:

```
ValueError: The file 'app/static_file.js' could not be found with <django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.CachedStaticFilesStorage object at 0x80910a9d0>
```

In fact, you can't run any django command, as it tries to load the admin app and it fails when it gets to the point of trying to run the `static` command on the static file that hasn't been collected yet.

Does anyone have any ideas of a way around this?

Comment: I ran into this also. It seems the Django team is working on a fix for this. https://github.com/django/django/pull/5571/files

Comment: Here is the ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21221

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this, in case anyone else comes across this issue. You can set a media property on the ModelAdmin class to return the Media class and defer the loading of the media.

```
from django.forms import Media

@property
def media(self):
    js = [
        'app/static_files.js',
        'app/static_files_2.js',
    ]

    return Media(js=[static(path) for path in js])
```

Comment: Got the same issue and the workaround works for me. Not sure if it worth reporting it as a bug since usage of the `static` tag outside template files is not documented.

Comment: I have been too enthusiastic! This solution does not render the field's Media.

Answer (score 1):

Here a snippet inspired from OP's one that manage the Media from the widgets:

```
from django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_static import static
from django.forms import Media

def get_cached_media(form, js, css):
    """Fix collectstatic when using CachedStaticFilesStorage """
    media = Media(js=[static(path) for path in js],
                css=dict([
                    (key, [static(path) for path in paths])
                    for key, paths in css.items()
                ]))
    if form.fields:
        for field in form.fields.values():
            media = media + field.widget.media
    return media
```

That you can use like that in your forms:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # fields

    @property
    def media(self):
        js = ['my/js/stuffs.js']
        css = {
            'all': (
                'my/css/forms.css',
                'my/css/stuffs.css',
            )
        }
        return get_cached_media(self, js, css)
```

So that in your template, if you use the `{{ my_form.media }}` tag, media from widgets will be rendered too.